# як пишеться по-батькові?

Tags: орфографія, разом-дефіс-окремо

як пишеться по-батькові - через дефіс/ разом/ чи окремо??

коли навчалась в школі було через дефіс, а зараз зустрічала окремо.

> *по батькові*
>   сполука
>   незмінювана словникова одиниця

Comment: Ніколи не посалося "по батькові" через дефіс. Дефіс -- це видумка "грамотєїв"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**По батькові**](http://sum.in.ua/s/batjko) — складова частина власного імені людини, що вказує на ім'я батька.

> *Бригадирів знає [Шагайда] на ім'я і **по батькові*** — Василь Кучер, Чорноморці, 1956, 11.