# "по батьковi" - іменник?

Tags: вживання-слів

Як граматично правильно використовувати "по батькові"? Чи вірно побудована фраза ***"Українські по батькові [фіксуються джерелами починаючи з  століття]"***?

На мою думку, "по батькові" не є іменником і не може бути підметом.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko Та бачу я, про що мова. Ви питання моє зрозуміли? Допомогти з відповіддю можете?

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko *Розпишіть зміст* - Так ви ж уже відповіли по суті.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> «[По батькові](https://answiki.org.ua/1417-yak-pyshetsya-po-batkovi.html)» — це прислівник, який,  згідно з українським
> правописом, маємо писати окремо.
>
> [Прислі́вник](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) (лат. adverbium — «до дієслова», «при дієслові») — це
> незмінна самостійна частина мови, що виражає ознаку дії, стан предмета
> або ознаку якості і відповідає на питання як? де? звідки? наскільки?
> якою мірою?
>
> Прислівник у реченні пов'язується з дієсловом, виконуючи роль
> обставини дії, наприклад: Синіла (де?) навкруги далечінь (Гончар);
> Дорога все глибше (як?) врізалась в ущелину, зверху (звідки?), зі
> скель, покапувало. (М. Олійник)
>
> Рідше прислівник входить у зв'язок з іменником, виконуючи роль
> неузгодженого означення: Карлос вибрав шлях (який?) направо, Гвідо
> вибрав шлях (який?) наліво. (Леся Українка) Менш типовою для частини
> прислівників є роль присудка в односкладному реченні: Тихо, пустельно,
> мов на краю світу. (О. Гончар)

Або ж ім'я по батькові.

> [Обста́вина](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) — другорядний член речення, який пояснює слово зі
> значенням ознаки, виражає якісно-означальну характеристику дії, стану
> чи позначає, за яких обставин відбувається дія, вказує на спосіб, міру
> або ступінь вияву дії або ознаки. Типовим, морфологізованим,
> вираженням обставини є прислівник як? де? коли? звідки? для чого?
> чому? наскільки? якою мірою? Обставина може виражатися відмінковими
> формами іменника з прийменниками або без них, дієприслівником,
> інфінітивом і фразеологічними зворотами прислівникового значення.
> Підкреслюється на письмі штрихпунктиром: _ . _ . _ . _ .
>
> [По батькові](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2927/%D1%8F%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96) — складова частина власного імені людини, що вказує на
> ім'я батька.

Тобто у виразі "Українські по батькові" ви пропустили слово "ім'я". Бо мова йде про складову частину імені людини по батькові.

Comment: ОК. Дякую. *Тобто у виразі "Українські по батькові" ви пропустили слово "ім'я". * - Це не я. )))

Answer (score 0):

Наскільки я розумію, будь яке слово чи словосполучення в певних контекстах може відігравати роль іменника й бути підметом. Наприклад:

> Твоє «пробач» (або: твоє «будь ласка», твоє «чи я тобі не заважаю?») мені вже остогидло.

або

> Звідси ясно, що в своїй роздвоєності поет цілий, що і закривавлене *вчора* і осяяне *завтра* — лише дві іпостасі одного: днів, життя людського, як воно крізь погляд поетів відбивається (Максим Рильський, «Про двох поетів», 1926).

Comment: Це інше. Мені важко висловити це українською омовою, але в ваших прикладах слова в "лапках" використовуються не в прямому значенні. Проти ***"Ваше "по батьковi" мені набридло"***  я б не заперечував. Але я питав про "по батьковi" без лапок.

Comment: @behemothus, можу помилятися, але мені здається — чим частіше щось використовується в ролі іменника, тим менше бажання явно ставити біля нього лапки. От другий приклад (про закривавлене вчора й осяяне завтра) без лапок.

Comment: Другий приклад - я ще не рoзбiрав, важко, )) Думатиме.